# How do I enable TypeScript's SourceMap option in VSNET 2013 Virtual Project?

Tags: typescript

I use VSNET 2013 to update TypeScript directly in an IIS folder.  VS.NET generates the accompanying javascript file.  In Tools - Options, there's a way to tell TypeScript to always generate for files that aren't in a project (VSNET shows them as items in a virtual project).

I can't work out how to tell TS to create the source map file though in this case.  Hoping you guys can share some tips.

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can control generation of source maps via `sourceMap` option in `tsconfig.json` file. Set it to `true` and you should be fine.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    ...
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
}
```